# Serious issue from production convert from string to decimal issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

actually I have developed a web application in MVC 5.0 with Entity framework 6.0, sql server ..

I tried to query a sum value which is Amount(Float in sql server)

```
SearchDetails.Sum(total => Convert.ToDecimal(total.Amount));
```

getting

> input string was not in a correct format

I took database backup and I tried to run from my side I am getting the value

I have verified in the database all the values are in correct format

I tried to print the values

```
total.Amount
```

getting a comma

```
","
```

instead of dot

```
"."
```

in my PC value is like 300.00 but the same in client PC getting 300,00 ?

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a localization/culture issue.  Is the client an international client?  You might look at the [overload that accepts culture info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The exception message clearly indicates that there is some `string` conversion involved. So, actually what is the **type** of `total.Amount`?

Comment: Var totalam=total amount

Comment: localization/culture issue it sounds like we are close ,,, how can i change the localization/culture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Add this in

in globlization section SET culture = en-US

this solved my issue

Thanks